# Where should I install firebase admin SDK?

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-admin

I'm developing a website using firebase web services. I need to add admin SDK to manage users.

Inside my local project folder, there are 2 folders that i get confuse,

[snapshot of the main directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwv9o.jpg)

My main directory has node_modules folder and also functions folder contain another node_modules sub folder and only functions folder has **package.json** file.

[inside functions folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46m7m.jpg)

Where should I open command prompt and run this code to install admin SDK into my website?

'''npm install firebase-admin --save'''

Do I need to go into functions folder or just run the code in my main directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing any node module, run the npm command from the location of package.json.  For Cloud Functions projects created by the Firebase CLI, this will be the functions folder by default.

Comment: Thank you so much. So I can open cmd inside root/functions folder and install all the required node modules and run them on firebase server. Am I right?

Comment: Sure, you can do that.